# node js npm start error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I started learn nodejs by following this tutorial [MEAN STACK](https://github.com/hwz/chirp/tree/master/module-3)

Now I am at module 3, and when I start npm start command. I got the following error.
Here is the error: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/JAksxX3Q)

Comment: Do you always have this with the last version ?

Comment: I tried to code my self with guidanc from git source code.
And I already doublce check my code multiple times, and I think my code just same with git version.

I really confused, because the error log isnt really descriptive

Comment: In your `package.json` file you have defined `"start" : "./bin/www"`  this folder contain any file or start file (index.js) ?

Comment: I did deleted index.js

Because in the tutorial thet delete it too.

and in .bin/www there ara no reference to index.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be forget defining start script in package.json file. it should be like this.

```
"scripts": {
"start": "node ./bin/www"
},
```

Article define very well. have a look [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)

Comment: no I am not forget about that. its already defined in package.json

Comment: just try . open cmd on root folder and hit node ./bin/www

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, when i tried that it gives me the following stack strace : [link](http://pastebin.com/ZYmfkt4y)

Comment: Hi deepak thank you for your answer, because of your answer now I can trace my error.

My problem is now resolved. the problem is in authenticate.js.

Comment: dou u have another usefull tips / trick to do error trace in node js or some good video tutorial regarding node fundamental?
Because i am very new to node.

Comment: yes.. sure.. this may help you.. https://www.udemy.com/node-js-training-and-fundamentals/

raise thumbs up to answer if you found helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

The first error received is a generic npm error thrown when it runs a script and the script fails.  In this case, the `./bin/www` script is failing as shown in lines 29 to 31 of your first [stack trace](http://pastebin.com/JAksxX3Q):

```
> 17 error module-3@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
> 17 error Exit status 1
> 18 error Failed at the module-3@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
```

Running the script directly from the command line with `> node ./bin/www` confirms that the script throws an error upon execution.

> Error: Route.post() requires callback functions but got a [object Object]

This seems like the `post` method is receiving some non-`function` arguments.  I would look for stack trace lines that refer to this project's code as `route.js` is some well-established code from the Express framework.

---

> at module.exports (C:\Users\prk\Documents\Learn node.js\MEAN MVA\module-3\routes\authenticate.js:16:12)

As per the [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router.METHOD), all arguments to the `Router.post()` method beyond the first one must be functions.  It seems whatever is happening at this line passes a non-`function` value to `Router.post`.  If it's following the git repo closely, looks like `passport.authenticate()` is returning an object instead of a function.  You'll need to perform some more debugging to find out.